# Issue of getting more items in List(Actions on google)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am developing a shopping bot in that user will ask for the product and then i will be fetching the results from the database and the results will be more than 10 items. I know that the default items for the list is 10 items. My question here is how to add a more button at the end of the list so that i can load more of the items into the list.

```
for(var p=0;p<=countforchunk;p++)
{
  items[p] = {
    optionInfo: {
      key: (p + 1).toString(),
      synonyms: temparray[p],
    },
    title: temparray[p],
    url: "https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.pixabay.com%2Fphoto%2F2015%2F04%2F23%2F22%2F00%2Ftree-736885__340.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fpixabay.com%2Fimages%2Fsearch%2Fnature%2F&tbnid=_2JirDBiGzi3lM&vet=12ahUKEwi71YPNxdrnAhVJGbcAHVi_BdEQMygAegUIARCFAg..i&docid=Ba_eiczVaD9-zM&w=546&h=340&q=images&ved=2ahUKEwi71YPNxdrnAhVJGbcAHVi_BdEQMygAegUIARCFAg",
    image: new Image({
      url: imgarray1[p],
      alt: imgarray1[p]
    }),
  }
  conv.ask(new List({
    title: 'Search Results',
    items: items
  }));
  resolve();
}
```

[image]

Please help me out,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell - there is no *technical* limit of 10 items. If you put 12 items in a list, for example, it will show 12 items.

This is not, however, a very good idea. (Even 10 items is a lot, and you should be thinking about voice interaction, where you might not want to read back more than 2 or 3). So at some point you will want to think about paging anyway.

If you do, you need to implement this as another Intent and Intent Handler. You can do this by offering a suggestion chip that says "Show me more" and accepting training phrases such as "more", "what else", and "show me more" in the Intent. You can use a Context to keep track of where you are in the result list.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep track of loaded item. There is limitation of loading 30 items at a time.

When user wants more item, you have handle that voice intent and can store current page index in context and based on that you can add another 30 items by replacing existing one.

1-30 items = page 1
30-60 items = page 2 and so on.

Call an api accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by voice intent? Is it default or we have to add an intent for this.

Comment: You have to add it. Like when user says "more item", "load more", "show me more items"etc

Comment: Is there any way to add the more button at the end of the list instead of calling other intent

Comment: You can use suggestion chips I believe

Comment: I have edited my question with the exact output i need